# Reading script from stdin

Tags: c

I have one program with:

```
sprintf(cmd,
"ftpx -n %s > ftp_get.out <<END_SCRIPT\n"
"quote USER %s\n"
"quote PASS %s\n"
"bin\n"
"cd  %s\n"
"get %s\n"
"quit\n"
"END_SCRIPT\n",host,user,password,dir,fileName);

system(cmd);
```

Just downloads a file via ftp.  Works as expected.

Except that I actually want to run my own executable called ftpx.  But I can't figure out how to read the lines between the END_SCRIPT tags.  I thought a simple read from stdin would work:

```
// ftpx
while(fgets(buf,4096,stdin))
{
    fprintf(logFile,"   INN %d %s\n",++i,buf);
}
```

But no luck.  So what is the trick for reading those lines?

Comment: What? Your example *does* run `ftpx`, and you claim that it works? And yes, the text up until the `<<END_SCRIPT` should be available on `stdin`.

Comment: It works when I use the ftp executable.  Just wanted to make clear that the problem was not in building the command.  But when I change ftp to ftpx, my executable runs but I don't seem to be able to get the lines.  But if you say it should work then I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  The problem was elsewhere.  Reading from stdin does work.